# php form header and cookie problems

Tags: php, forms, cookies

Can anyone see why my two files aren't working? I'm putting the cookie data at the top, so im not sure why im still getting header errors. (BTW, i have to use cookies here, not sessions so i have to work with what i have)

```
    <?php
ob_start();
?>

<?php

$browser = get_browser();

$_SESSION['ip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
echo "<b>Welcome user. You ip is: ".$_SESSION['ip']." and your using ".$browser->browser." as your browser.</b>";

echo "<form action=\"form_data.php\" method=\"post\">";
echo "Your username:<input type=\"text\" name=\"username\" size=\"20\"><br/>";
echo "Your password:<input type=\"codeword\" name=\"codeword\" size=\"20\"><br/>";
echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit data\" />";
echo "<br /><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"submitted\" value=\"true\" />";
?>

<?php
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

form_data.php

```
<?php
setcookie('username',$_POST['username']);
setcookie('password', $_POST['codeword']);
header("Location:form_data.php");

echo "<b>Thanks, </b>".$_COOKIE['username']. " <br />";
echo "Your codeword is ".$_COOKIE['codeword']."<br />";
echo "Started here: ".date("g:i a").", " .date("F j, Y");
echo "<br/>IP Address: ".$_SESSION['ip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
?>
```

Comment: Generally, the error message tells where the error occurred. What does your error message say?

Comment: If you're not using sessions, why are you setting things to $_SESSION?  Also, what file and line is the header error coming from?

Comment: your php tag <?php is opening after output of 4 or 5 white spaces that's why header is giving error..and also suggested to write header("location: form_data.php"); instead  header("location:form_data.php");. Please mind the space after location:. It may be reflecting.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?php
ob_start();
?>
```

Notice the 4 spaces before your opening `<?php`. Since those appear BEFORE the php opening tag, they're considered output. If you want to do output buffer and output headers throughout, PHP's opening tag has to be absolutely the first thing in the file. This includes the unicode BOM, whitespace, etc...

Answer (score 0):

remove this line:

```
header("Location:form_data.php");
```

the line would redirect to form_data.php. but your are in the form_data file => redirect loop

and i would not save a password as a cookie. it's really easy to steal those password